# Testcafe - how do I iterate over selectors of different element types?

Tags: reactjs, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I have a React address form which is config driven, and each element could either be a text `<input>` or a `<select>` dropdown. When trying to fill in the form using the code below, the text inputs are populated successfully, but the select element can't be found. If I remove the select elements from the loop and select them individually afterwards, it works fine. The `MOCKS.deliveryAddress` values are just strings.

```
  const addressFields = {
    addressLine2: Selector('[data-testid="input-addressLine2"]'),
    addressLine1: Selector('[data-testid="input-addressLine1"]'),
    addressLine3: Selector('[data-testid="input-addressLine3"]'),
    addressLine4: Selector('[data-testid="input-addressLine4"]'),
    postalCode: Selector('[data-testid="input-postalCode"]'),
  };

  const fieldConfig = {
    addressLine1: 'text',
    addressLine2: 'text',
    addressLine3: 'text',
    addressLine4: 'select',
    postalCode: 'text',
  };

  const enterAddress = async () => {
    await Promise.all(
      Object.keys(addressFields).map(async (field) => {
        if (fieldConfig[field] === 'text') {
          if (MOCKS.deliveryAddress[field]) {
            await t.typeText(
              addressFields[field],
              MOCKS.deliveryAddress[field],
              {
                replace: true,
              },
            );
          }
        } else {
          await t.click(addressFields[field]);
          await t.click(
            addressFields[field]
              .find('option')
              .withText(MOCKS.deliveryAddress[field]),
          );
        }
      }),
    );
  };
}
```

I get the error `1) The element that matches the specified selector is not visible.`

Am I doing something wrong here in how I handle the selector inside a `map`?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I was doing it wrong! I should have been chaining the click events for opening the dropdown and selecting an option, rather than awaiting the `select` click and then awaiting the `option` click. E.g.

```
await t
  .click(addressFields[field])
  .click(
    addressFields[field]
    .find('option')
    .withText(MOCKS.deliveryAddress.addressLine4),
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the TestCafe [documentation](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/reference/test-api/domnodestate.html#members-specific-to-element-nodes), the element is considered as 'visible' if it does not have `display: none` or `visibility: hidden` CSS properties and has non-zero width and height. Using the browser development tool to investigate the properties of elements used in tests.

Comment: Unfortunately the visibility of the element isn't actually the problem. When the test runs, the element is visible on the page. And it can be found if the same selector is used outside of the `map` callback.